# Transform an Array into specific XML

Tags: xml, cakephp

I'd like to transform this given array

```
array(
    'podcast' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Podcast' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'xmlurl' => 'http://test2.com'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Podcast' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'xmlurl' => 'http://test4.com'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

into this String with CakePHP 2.3.6:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<opml version="2.0">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <outline xmlUrl="http://test2.com" />
        <outline xmlUrl="http://test4.com" />
    </body>
</opml>
```

How would I do this? I know there is a [Doc here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml), but I would appreciate help nevertheless.

This is what I have so far:

```
$new = array();
foreach($podcasts as $p):
    $pod['xmlurl'] = $p['Podcast']['xmlurl'];
endforeach;
$new['opml']['body']['outline'][]=$pod;
debug($new);

$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($new);
$xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();
debug($xmlString);
```

Output `debug($xmlString)`:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml>
    <body>
      <outline>
        <xmlurl>http://test1.com</xmlurl>
      </outline>
    </body>
</opml>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to transform it into a format as described in the linked Cookbook article, so that CakePHP can recognize it. Use `@` to indicate attributes, and let `Xml::fromArray()` return an `DOMDocument` instance so that you can set [`DOMDocument::xmlStandalone`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.xmlstandalone) to `true`.

This:

```php
$podcasts = array(
    'podcast' => array(
        array(
            'Podcast' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'xmlurl' => 'http://test2.com'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'Podcast' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'xmlurl' => 'http://test4.com'
            )
        )
    )
);

$new = array (
    'opml' => array (
        '@version' => '2.0',
        'head' => null
    )
);

foreach($podcasts['podcast'] as $p) {
    $new['opml']['body']['outline'][] = array (
        '@xmlurl' => $p['Podcast']['xmlurl']
    );
};

$dom = Xml::fromArray($new, array('return' => 'domdocument'));
$dom->xmlStandalone = true;

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

will generate the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<opml version="2.0">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <outline xmlurl="http://test2.com"/>
        <outline xmlurl="http://test4.com"/>
    </body>
</opml>
```